# showing buffer list whilst moving through buffer list

Tags: buffers

Is there a way to show the list of buffers whilst moving through them?

ie. `next buffer` would ideally also pop up a list of buffers to show the buffers that are coming up next

Comment: What about `C-x b` (`switch-to-buffer`) isn't what you want?

Comment: it kind of is but it doesn't open the buffer in the current window. ideally it'll be `switch-to-prev` and `switch-to-next` and automatically closing the minibuffer when a command other than the previous two are given (instead of opening up the minibuffer and using arrowkeys)

Comment: I still don't understand this question.  Do you think you could give an excruciatingly explicit example showing a sequence of keypresses or commands, and the resulting behaviour at each step?

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then `C-x b` (and other commands that let you choose a buffer, e.g. `C-x k`) let you cycle and otherwise navigate to any number of buffers.

This is because they are [multi-commands](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands): You can act on any of them individually, using `C-RET` (or `C-down` etc., to act and cycle at the same time). And you can filter them with your minibuffer content and then act on all of them, using `C-!`.